# XXE Prevention of Spring Webservice Soap Reaquest

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, spring-ws, xxe

I am using JaxWS-Spring jar and Jaxb for generating my SOAP Webservice API.
Now I want to handle XXE prevention, please help how I can do that.

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="customerEndpoint" class="org.webservicespring.ws.CustomerEndpointService">
    </bean>
    <wss:binding url="/customer">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#customerEndpoint" />
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>
```